# Need Design suggestion for Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have 2 tables in my application named as:

1. Facilities (id, name, logo)
2. Packages (id, name, duration, amount, paymentplan, facilityid)

Facilities is quite simple. In Packages, paymentplan is either **onetime** or **recurring(installment)**.
Till now, its all gonna do the job.

Now the requirement is:
Packages can be of duration **2, 3 or 5 years** but amount should be deducted from the customer till **6 months or say 12 months**.

Example:
A customer takes a 5 years package (e.g. $5000) and wants to pay the package amount monthly in a 1 year duration ($5000 / 12). In this case, customer will avail services for 5 years but pay amount in 12 months installments.

How should I approach this requirement?

Should I go for an extra column of **payment_duration**?

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear to me, but it sounds like you're saying:

> If `paymentplan` is recurring, then the customer pays `amount` on a recurring basis (monthly?) for either 6 months or 12 months.
>
> If `paymentplan` is onetime, then the customer pays `amount` once.

I suggest you need a third table:

3. Payments (id, packageId, amount, duedate, paymentdate)

When you create a Package, also create 1, 6, or 12 rows in Payments. Then you can fill in the amount to be paid on each future installment. The duedate is the date it is due. Paymentdate is NULL initially, because the customer hasn't paid it yet. When the customer pays, set the paymentdate to the date they made the payment (this might be before or after duedate).

This allows you to find payments that are not paid and are past their due date:

```
SELECT ... FROM Payments WHERE paymentdate IS NULL AND duedate < NOW()
```

Comment: Thanks @bill-karwin. However, I am asking that the client offers a package in which he asks clients to pay amount of 5 years in 1 year (installments) and avail the services for 5 years. So, the payments schedule will be for 1 year and package membership for 5 years.

Comment: My answer would be the same. You make 12 rows in Payments, each for $416.66, with due dates every month. The package may still be for 5 years duration.

Comment: But I need to track user input that how many months the payment is going to be recurring/installments. We have to mention that the installments can be paid in how many months. It's not fixed to 12 months only. But on Package creation, the admin will mention total no of installments for the package.

Comment: If it's not 12 months, then insert some different number of rows in the Payments table.